# Julia: String interpolation of Array element

Tags: arrays, julia

I can interpolate a variable into a string to print the value with other text like this:

```
a = "sheriff";
println("Howdy, I'm the $a.")

Howdy, I'm the sheriff.
```

I need the syntax for interpolating an array element, I'm currently getting this:

```
A = ["carb", "sheriff", "mumchance"]
println("Howdy, I'm the $A[2].")

Howdy, I'm the String["carb", "sheriff", "mumchance"][2].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm posting this Q/A because I spent too much time looking for this.

```
println("Howdy, I'm the $(A[2]).")
```

String interpolation in Julia is similar to unix shells. You can interpolate expressions by wrapping them in parentheses.

[Julia Documentation: Strings/Interpolation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/strings/#string-interpolation-1)

Comment: Thanks, also looked far too long before coming across this answer. It's worth noting that this also works for something like `println("Howdy, I'm the $(A["key"]).")` when dealing with dictionaries.